# Calculating effect size and post-hoc power from mean difference in a meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

[image]

I wish to calculate the power of each included study to detect the "true" treatment effect. For pregabalin the mean difference is -33.14. As far as I understand one way to achieve this is to calculate the pooled SD using the 95% confidence interval estimate(s).

SD = (-53.98-(-33.14))/1.96*sqrt(235+151) = 208.898

Hence, the Cohen´s d is 33.14/208.898=0.15864.

Then, using the sample sizes above I can estimate the power of each study included to detect this certain effect size.

Is my interpretation valid or should I use the raw data (means and SDs) from each study to estimate the effect size?

Comment: You do appreciate that post-hoc power is a controversial topic? What is the scientific question which has given rise to this issue?

Comment: @mdewey I do appreciate that. I do not calculated post-hoc power of a single study. I estimate the post-hoc power of individual studies to detect the pooled effect size using the sample sizes in individual studies. The idea is as in the highly cited work by Button et al. 2013